# no1 record in uptimed report

Tags: uptime

I have recently installed [uptimed](https://github.com/rpodgorny/uptimed) to track history of when my electricity was off. Everything is clear but there's one thing I cannot decipher.

What does the label "no1" stand for in the following report? It points to a future date (it's March 7, here).

```bsh
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ uprecords
     #               Uptime | System                                     Boot up
----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------
     1     0 days, 22:18:45 | Linux 4.14.98-v7+         Fri Mar  6 15:46:56 2020
->   2     0 days, 00:00:51 | Linux 4.14.98-v7+         Sat Mar  7 14:05:56 2020
----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------
no1 in     0 days, 22:17:55 | at                        Sun Mar  8 12:24:41 2020
    up     0 days, 22:19:36 | since                     Fri Mar  6 15:46:56 2020
  down     0 days, 00:00:15 | since                     Fri Mar  6 15:46:56 2020
   %up               99.981 | since                     Fri Mar  6 15:46:56 2020
```

Answer (score 2):

That line tells you how long until you take the number 1 slot: if your system stays up for another 22:17:55, the then-current uptime will be greater than any recorded so far by `uptimed`. Thus, if the system stays up without rebooting until then, at 12:24:41 on March 8, running `uprecords` would show

```
     #               Uptime | System                                     Boot up
----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------
->   1     0 days, 22:18:45 | Linux 4.14.98-v7+         Sat Mar  7 14:05:56 2020
     2     0 days, 22:18:45 | Linux 4.14.98-v7+         Fri Mar  6 15:46:56 2020
----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------
    up     1 days, 20:37:30 | since                     Fri Mar  6 15:46:56 2020
  down     0 days, 00:00:15 | since                     Fri Mar  6 15:46:56 2020
   %up               99.991 | since                     Fri Mar  6 15:46:56 2020
```

Once you have more uptimes recorded, `uprecords` will show more such entries at the bottom of its output; for example, on one of my systems:

```
1up in     0 days, 22:26:32 | at                        Tue Mar 10 08:51:32 2020
t10 in     8 days, 16:56:11 | at                        Wed Mar 18 03:21:11 2020
no1 in   218 days, 11:02:55 | at                        Tue Oct 13 22:27:55 2020
```

which means my current “run” will move up one place in the rankings tomorrow at 8:51, will enter the top ten on March 18, and will assume the number one spot on October 13 (assuming it doesn’t end before then, by powering off or rebooting).